# How to create dynamic data frame from S3 files in Glue Job in Scala?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, etl, aws-glue

I'm having problems in converting a Python Glue Job to Scala Glue Job, namely `create_dynamic_data_frame_options` method. In python the syntax is:

```
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("s3",
                                        {'paths': file_paths},
                                         format="csv",
                                       format_options={"separator": ",", "quoteChar": '"'})
```

where file_paths is a list `['s3://bucket1/file1.txt','s3://bucket2/file2.txt']` . How to do the same thing in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
val file_paths = Array(
    "s3://bucket/data1",
    "s3://bucket/data2"
)

val dyf = glueContext.getSourceWithFormat(
    connectionType = "s3", 
    options = JsonOptions(Map("paths" -> file_paths)), 
    format = "csv", 
    formatOptions = JsonOptions(Map("separator" -> ",", "quoteChar": "\""))
).getDynamicFrame()
```